# is there anyway i can pass an array to getAll()?

Tags: rethinkdb

I am looking for a good way to do the following.

1. Get a list of uids from tableA like..

`r.Table('tableA').get(1)('somelistofuid')`

2. Then I want to use the list go get all the data I need from tableB

`r.Table('tableB').getAll(listfromQueryAbove)`

I know that i can do getAll(a,b,c) to get a,b,c but could there be a simpler way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want something to unpack an array into an argument list, that's [args](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/args/).

So change your query to

```
r.Table('tableB').getAll(r.args(listfromQueryAbove))
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `r.args` for this:

```
r.table('table').getAll(r.args(ARRAY))
```